How can I mix inheritance strategies (SINGLE_TABLE and TABLE_PER_CLASS) with Hibernate 6.5/JPA?
I am trying to design an entity model with inheritance that also supports maintaining draft and publish states  of the entities. I am using JPA annotations with Hibernate implementation (version 6.5). I have the following entity model

abstract Message

abstract TextRoot

Text

TextPublish
TextDraft




abstract WhatsappRoot

Whatsapp

WhatsappPublish
WhatsappDraft







Here is what I want to achieve

all of the classes here are entities and I want to support polymorphic queries (i.e. fetch all Messages or fetch all Texts)
I want to create tables for all of the entities I have highlighted in bold to represent a single table for each sub hierarchy
The entities highlighted in bold will have "publish" and "draft" entities and the entities highlighted in bold will have tables that contain both publish and draft entities

I tried using a mix of two JPA inheritance strategies, SINGLE_TABLE and TABLE_PER_CLASS. I annotated Message with TABLE_PER_CLASS and annotate Text and Whatsapp with SINGLE_TABLE. I do understand as per JPA spec it isn't recommended. However, I believe I need both strategies because I need an inheritance strategy to be applied to the root class so that I can tell Hibernate I want to support polymorphic queries at that level but create a table per "sub hierarchy" by using SINGLE_TABLE.
In the end it didn't work as expected - Hibernate seems to ignore the SINGLE_TABLE inheritance strategy and generate DDLs using only the TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance strategy applied on the Message entity class.
**Can anyone suggest how I try to achieve a mixed inheritance strategy for my use case?
**
